# Email Signature - VBscript for Word, with tables

Tags: email, vbscript, ms-word

I'm trying to set a company signature and then implement it with GPO.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
John Hancock | Paralegal | Company, PC
<Logo (to the left of text)> 60 Test Street | PO Box 1389 | Testing, PA 19820 
Phone: 555.555.5555| Fax: 555.555.5555 | Email: testing@testing.com (need this hyperlinked)
```

EDIT: Additional information from comments.

I'm trying to have different attributes (font size, font type, bold, etc) for the text in each particular line within the second row of the table. For example: Test text (this is bold and Calibri) - Test Text 2 (this is not bold and Arial). When I run the script as it stands, I get the logo on the left, in the first column, and a line of text to the right of the logo, in the second column. What I can't figure out is how to add another line of text, on the right, directly underneath the first line, and have that line of text show with different font attributes and such.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FullName
strFirst = objUser.FirstName
strLast = objUser.LastName
strInitials = objUser.Initials
strOffice = objUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
strPOBox = objUser.postOfficeBox
strTitle = objUser.Description
strCred = objUser.info
strStreet = objUser.StreetAddress
strLocation = objUser.l
strPostCode = objUser.PostalCode
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strFax = objUser.FacsimileTelephoneNumber
strEmail = objUser.mail
strCompany = objUser.Company


Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 1
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature

Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

Set objShape = objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("\\eg-fileserver\admin space\signature\logo.jpg"), "http://www.eastburngray.com",,,"")
objTable.Columns(1).Width = 20
objTable.Columns(2).Width = 320
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Size = 10
objTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = strFirst & strInitials & strLast & " | " & strOffice & " | " & strCompany

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

objSignatureEntries.Add "Full Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Full Signature"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

Comment: Formatting for what I'm trying to accomplish wasn't correct.  My apologies.  I'm trying to have three lines to the right of the logo.

Comment: First thing of all: remove the line On Error Resume Next. That turns off error messages for the code. You need the error messages to tell you what's going wrong. We can't help you without that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to adding text with various formatting in Word is to work with a Range object. You can think of a Range like an invisible Selection, with the major difference that you can have as many Range objects as you need - there can be only one Selection. The trick to changing the formatting is to "collapse" the Range (think of it like pressing the Right- or Left-Arrow keys to a blinking "point", then continuing to type).

Edit Note: Based on bibadia's surmise that this is actually about VBScript and *not VBA* I've changed the tags in your question and am editing my Answer to fit VBScript. VBScript cannot use Word-specific object declarations and enumerations, so I've removed the "Dim As" and replaced all wdEnum with the Integer equivalent.

Using your code as a starting point, the approach could look something like this:

```
Dim rngCell 
Set rngCell = objTable.Cell(1,2).Range
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
rngCell.Text = strFirst & strInitials & strLast & " | " & _
               strOffice & " | " & strCompany & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = True
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, -1
rngCell.Text = strPhone & " | " & strFax & " | " & strEmail
rngCell.Font.Bold = False
rngCell.Font.Size = 8
```

Note 1: The order in which you do things is usually reversed from that when typing as a user: First populate the Range, then apply the formatting.

Note 2: When collapsing at the end of a cell, Word will move the Range position to the beginning of the following cell. Thus, the code moves the point back one character, putting it at the end of the previous (original) cell: `rngCell.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1`

Note 3: I added a `vbCr` at the end of the first `rngCell.Text` to create the new paragraph within the table cell.

Comment: @Razdell OK, I've edited my answer for VBScript, as well as your original question. VBScript is NOT VBA, so if you need to ask more questions please keep that in mind and target the question accordingly.

Comment: You rock, Cindy!  I really appreciate your help and patience.  I got the important part setup exactly how I want it now.  The last thing I need to do is insert text after the table and then I'm finished.  Should I create a new question or can you help me with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393260/how-can-i-move-cursor-to-end-of-table-in-word-application/34398416#34398416

Comment: Thanks again, Cindy.  I actually ended up resolving it with objSelection.EndKey END_OF_STORY

Comment: OK. Just so there are no unexpected surprises: That will always put the SELECTION (where the user ends up) at the end of the document, not specifically after the table.